# Forms not working after .htaccess URL rewrite

Tags: php, forms, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I copied the below code from some other posts. It successfully helped me to strip the .php extension from the URL. However, after implementing this, some of my forms are no longer working. I have forms that are posting like

```
<form method='post' action='/users/activate/Qwerty'></form>
```

Now it is not sending the data to the location when I submit the form. I realize that if I change the `action='/users/activate/Qwerty'` to `action='?action=activate&code=Qwerty123'`, the forms will work again. But there are a number of pages that contain forms posting to different locations in my website, and I do not want to change so many of them manually. So I wouold like to know why the data are not posting as expected and how can I solve the problem?

My .htaccess is below

```
#the line below will hide folders and their contents on any apache server. Use 'Options +Indexes' to unhide
Options -Indexes

#the line below will hide folders and their contents on goDaddy. Use 'Options +MultiViews' to unhide
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#maintain post data after rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST


# Force WWW prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]


# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]   

#I want to rewrite the url http://127.0.0.1/users/activate/Qwerty123/ 
#so that I can get values with php like so $action = $_GET['action']; or $code=$_GET['id'];var_dump($action);//outputs visa var_dump($code);//outputs 203
#and also when the user makes a mistake and types http://127.0.0.1/users/activate/ it takes them to http://127.0.0.1/users.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/users/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)/?$ /users.php?action=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^users/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-,=]+)/?$  /users.php?action=$1&code=$2 [QSA,NC,L]



#the lines below relocate all 404 to the index page
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /index.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like the correct way to go about things. Why are you mixing GET and POST? Use $action = $_POST['action']; and add a <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ACTIONVALUEHERE"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lost `POST` data when submitting, it means you get a redirect.

This should be better now

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   # force WWW for remote servers (not localhost)
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.|localhost$) [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)$ [NC] 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

   # remove php extensions (only for GET method)
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php(?:\?|\s) [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule ^ %1/? [L,R=301]

   # don't touch other existing files/folders
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]

   # force trailing slash
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [L,R=301] 

   # rewrite extensionless php files
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L]

   # users activate
   RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ users.php?action=$1 [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ users.php?action=$1&code=$2 [NC,L]  

   # finally, if not found
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This link takes me to the index page http://127.0.0.1/users/activate/MXJOR3NIR3gyclBzZTVaYkgrOWxDdz09/ instead of taking me to users.php. This means I cannot post too

Comment: I fixed. Changed the lst lines to # users activate
   RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ users.php [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ users.php?action=$1&code=$2 [NC,L] . Thanks

Comment: Ok i had misunderstood what you wanted with that rule. I've edited my code, you can check if you have the same